# Getting error while downloading survey123 data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I've got a Python script `DownloadSurvey123Data.py` from ArcGIS community. Trying to run this script from Windows command prompt is throwing this error after the program starts:

```
agol_helper = ago.AGOLHelper(portal_url)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AGOLHelper'"
```

I saw in a comment in DownloadSurvey123Data.py that ago.py is part of Python 10.3. I have Python 2.7 installed in my PC, but don't how to get Python 10.3.

Here is the complete code:

```
import ago
import urllib.request as urllib2
import zipfile
import json


# ID of the feature service you want to export
featureService_ID = "b5eb865444ff417ba821f5f56ade54c3"
# Output format  Shapefile | CSV | File Geodatabase
output_format = 'CSV'
# Local folder where the data will be downloaded (include slash at the end)
download_folder = "D:/Temp/"
# ArcGIS user credentials to authenicate against the portal
credentials = { 'userName' : 'xxx', 'passWord' : 'Pxxxxw0rd'}
# Address of your ArcGIS portal
portal_url = r"https://iom-dev.maps.arcgis.com/sharing"

download_file = download_folder + 'download.zip'


def downloadFile(url, filename, token):
    """
    Downloads a file from the given URL.
    :param url: URL from which to download the file
    :param filename: Name of file to store the download locally. Proper permissions are assumed.
    :param token: Token for the portal identity
    :return:
    """
    print ("...Downloading")
    req = urllib2.urlopen(url + "?token=" + token)
    CHUNK = 16 * 1024
    with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
        while True:
            chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
            if not chunk: break
            fp.write(chunk)

def extractZIP(filename,folder):
    """
    Extracts the contents of the zip file into the specified folder.
    :param filename: The name of the ZIP archive to unpack. The file is assumed to exist.
    :param folder: The target folder to hold the content of the ZIP archive. Proper permissions are assumed.
    :return:
    """
    print ("...Extracting")
    zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
    zfile.extractall(folder)


print ("...Starting")
# initialize the portal helper class
# ago.py is part of the 10.3 python install
agol_helper = ago.AGOLHelper(portal_url)
print ("...Authenticating against your Portal ")
# login
agol_helper.login(credentials['userName'], credentials['passWord'])

# export url and parameters 
export_url = "{}/content/users/{}/export".format(agol_helper.secure_url, agol_helper.username)

export_parameters = {
    'token': agol_helper.token,
    'itemId': featureService_ID,
    'title': "Temp-" + str(int(round(time.time() * 1000))),
    'exportFormat': output_format,
    'f' :'json'
}
# launching async export request
export_data = agol_helper.url_request(export_url, export_parameters, request_type="POST")

if export_data is not None:
    print("ERROR: Can't find a feature service with id: " + featureService_ID)
    print("TIP:   Navigate to the item details page of your feature service, and get the id from the URL")
else:
    print ("...Exporting data")
    # retrieve the itemId for the export
    exportItemId = export_data['exportItemId']
    # retrieve the jobId to watch the export progress
    jobId = export_data['jobId']
    status = "processing"

    items_url = "{}/content/users/{}/items/{}/status".format(agol_helper.secure_url,agol_helper.username, exportItemId)
    data_url = "{}/content/items/{}/data".format(agol_helper.secure_url, exportItemId)

    status_parameters = {
        'jobId' : jobId,
        'jobType' : 'export',
        'f' : 'json',
        'token' : agol_helper.token
    }

    while status == "processing":
        print ("...." + status)
        # checking export job status
        time.sleep(5)
        data = agol_helper.url_request(items_url, status_parameters)

        status = data['status']

    if status == "completed":
        print ("...." + status)
        # once the export has completed, download the file
        downloadFile(data_url, download_file, agol_helper.token)
        # deleting export results in the portal
        agol_helper.delete(item_id=export_data['exportItemId'])
        # uncompress the contents of the archive
        extractZIP(download_file, download_folder)


    else:
        raise Exception("!!! Export job failed. Status \"" + status + "\"")

    print ("Completed. Files available at: " + download_folder )
```

The error is in line 54:

```
agol_helper = ago.AGOLHelper(portal_url)

Error Desc: "AttributeError: module 'ago' has no attribute 'AGOLHelper'"
```

Please note I have installed ArcGIS pro in my PC and am running Python script from this path:

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3>python.exe C:\Python27\DownloadSurvey123Data.py
```

Comment: Please post the entire script as text, so we can help you debug. Also there is no such thing as Python 10.3, you are probably referring to ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: Please always provide code snippets and full error messages (including line number) as text rather than pictures.

Comment: You have this tagged with arcgis-10.0, which has been retired for many years. Please [Edit] the question to accurately specify the exact software in use.

Comment: i have posted completed code.i have edited my post.please check..getting error in line no 54, may be ago library not loading

Comment: Ago is designed for ArcMap 10.3, not ArcGIS Pro. You have tagged this question with arcgis 10.0 which refers to ArcMap, not ArcGIS Pro. Going out on a limb here and guess that module "ago" is not compatible with ArcGIS Pro: `Project Status:
This project is no longer being actively developed.`  https://github.com/Esri/ago-tools

Comment: Project Status: This project is no longer being actively developed -  which mean can't use ago library? or i have to for licence version to use this ago library..

Answer (score 1):

Install ArcMap 10.3 or up and you should be able to use this module.

See [Esri's Github](https://github.com/Esri/ago-tools) for more information about their support for this module.