# Track changes in data Survey123

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-survey123

I need to track the changes in the data that have been edited in the surveys to later check them both to see what the changes were.
The workflow is as follows: a survey can be accepted or rejected by the supervisor, if it is rejected, a field is set in AGOL, so that it appears in the survey inbox 123, the field worker must correct it later with Survey123. However, we do not want to lose the information from the initial survey to have a record of the change and know what was done to that survey specifically.

Comment: As far as I am aware Survey123 doesn't allow this kind of versioning of data. I think it has to do with the way it is stored in AGOL. Unlike Portal for ArcGIS Online does not use Versioning (I could be wrong here). A solution would be to use a script to manually pull backups off AGOL at a given interval and create the versions in an offline Database for consumption on your side. Using the AGOL data purely for data capture. As I said, I am not 100% sure on this...but from my experience I cannot say I have found a way to access different versions of data stored online.

Comment: Many thanks, I pretty sure AGOL doen't use versioning. What is the best way to create a script to access the service and download the data? Postman?

Comment: Technically, this should be a second question. But have a look at this script. I use it all the time: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279432/getting-error-while-downloading-survey123-data/279726